# Difference Between two numbers without positive or negative in Ruby

Tags: ruby, subtraction, absolute-value

I want to find the difference between two numbers (positive integers) without returning any positive or negative sign.

Just like

```
Diff(2,5) => 3
Diff(5,2) => 3.
```

And Not

```
(2 - 5) => -3
```

Comment: What result do you expect for `diff(-2, 5)`? `3` or `7`?

Comment: @spickermann `-2 - 5` and `5 - -2` return `-7` and `7` respectively. `3` would be the _sum_, not the _difference_.

Comment: @Stefan I am sorry, I didn't explain my thinking. IMO the question is not clear for cases with negative input because it is not clear if the part _without the positive or the negative sign_ means only the output or the input too. `(a.abs - b.abs).abs != (a - b).abs`, but both versions might make sense depending on the OPs needs.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I want to find the difference between two numbers (positive integers) without returning any positive or negative sign." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, read the documentation of the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should simply return [absolute value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-abs):

```
def diff(a, b)
  (a - b).abs
end

diff(2, 5)
# => 3
```